# keeping copy of table day by day in the database

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I want to copy all the data from original table to duplicate table at every day 12 o clock. If I do so whatever changes happen that should reflect in duplicated table..like if we add new row that should added to duplicate table..more importantly if we change any column in original table that should also reflect in duplicate table without adding new row existing row attribute value should change.

```
@Override
public void insertDataToTableAtBegining() {

    Query itemQuery1 = entitymanager.createNativeQuery("INSERT graph_item SELECT * FROM item WHERE order_id IS NOT NULL");

    log.info("Inserting is completed where count is ZERO for item");

    itemQuery1.executeUpdate();

    Query orderQuery1 = entitymanager.createNativeQuery("INSERT graph_mrk_order SELECT * FROM mrk_order");

    log.info("Inserting is completed where count is ZERO for order");

    orderQuery1.executeUpdate();

}
@Override
public void insertDataToTable(Date beg, Date end) {

    Query itemQuery1;

    itemQuery1 = entitymanager.createNativeQuery("INSERT graph_item SELECT * FROM item WHERE create_timestamp BETWEEN '" + beg +"' AND '"+ end +"' WHERE order_id IS NOT NULL");
    log.info("Inserting is completed in Daily for item");

    itemQuery1.executeUpdate();


    Query orderQuery1;



    orderQuery1 = entitymanager.createNativeQuery("INSERT graph_mrk_order SELECT * FROM mrk_order WHERE create_timestamp BETWEEN '" + beg +"' AND '"+ end +"'");
    log.info("Inserting is completed in Daily for order");

    orderQuery1.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Talk to your DBA and let the DBA guys handle this. Don't do this from java code. Also your code is dangerous and will not work, never you String concat to create queries.

Comment: If you are going to attempt to keep the 'duplicate' table updated and in sync with the source table in an on-going fashion, then what is the purpose of the 'daily duplicate'?  For that matter, what is the purpose of the duplicate table at all?

Comment: we have to show the static graph of a present date.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggested you use a materialized view as it fits your case very well and you can guarantee that the materialized view has all the up to date rows from the original table.
In that case you'll only need to schedule the execution of the refresh of the materialized view.